# Matlab .Net Assembly compatible with .Net Core1.1

Tags: matlab, .net-core

I am trying to use Matab module compiled as .Net assembly in a .Net Core Project, but I receive the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or ass embly 'MWArray, Version=2.17.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=e1d84a0da19db8 6f'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.    at ConsoleAppCore1._1.Program.Main(String[] args)

MCR_R2017b_win64_installer.exe is installed on the system and I am able to load same Matlab module in .Net4.5 project.

Any clue to make it work with .Net Core1.1?

Answer (score 0):

Simply **NO** - mathworks supports only "classic"/desktop .net framework on Windows platforms

Please refer to this: [mathworks doc](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/system-requirements-for-using-matlab-interface-to-net-.html)